# meaning of "I won't let you down" in songs

Tags: idioms

I want to know the meaning and also the feeling that is transmitted by the sentence "I won't let you down" in songs.
thank you in anticipation

Comment: Hi Elnaz, you might want to take a look at this: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: See [*let down*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/let-down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means something like "I will not disappoint you".

Comment: Please don't answer questions that can be easily answered with a single dictionary lookup, and especially not if you're not gonna add anything else (i.e., don't just *answer the question* – in this case you haven't answered the entire question, even).